# Jmeter Token value extraction

Tags: regex, jmeter

Using Jmeter I was trying to extract the value of a token from the following, using the regular expression extractor:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" 
    value="BeRYiSIRjZoQHq4VW8qbkgXlnnzdUINpFNoYF_ugx-FRk0tkImbQPhwyYjyz_0Q-w6F2A0gDOfMZrdklD6rVn6-QnYggfImb55f90V7nrD_kbSkT3-y3gPqoTFg0ynTBLyX5Lw2" />
```

When I used the following expression:

```
name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.+?)"
```

the value was not extracted.

After a few searches I used the following expression:

```
name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="([A-Za-z0-9-_]+?)"
```

which worked, but I don't know why :d.

My question: why the first expression didn't worked since basically tells to extract any character that matches one or more times.

Comment: Use the regex tester in View Results Tree listener, and see what you get. I think the two statements are equivalent based on the input given.  The ? is redundant unless there is following data.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"\s*value="(.+?)"
```

or the best is

```
name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"\s*value="([^"]*)"
```

Both of yours will not work as between `type` and `value` there is a `\n` which you have not taken care of.Now it works.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/14

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [don't use Regular Expressions to extract data from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748). It is complicated and very fragile in case of even slight DOM changes.

JMeter provides the following components to extract data from HTML responses:

1. [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
2. [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)

**XPath Extractor Guide**

- Add Xpath Extractor as a child of the request which produces that response
- Configure it as follows:

  - Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
  - XPath query: `//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']/@value`
  - If your response is not valid XHTML check `Use Tidy` box
- Refer to extracted value as `${token}` or `${__V(token)}` where required. Remember that JMeter Variables scope is limited to current thread group only.

For more information see [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

**CSS/JQuery Extractor Guide**

- Add CSS/JQuery Extractor as a child of the request which produces that authentication token response
- Configure it as follows:

  - Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
  - CSS/JQuery expression: `input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]`
  - Attribute: `value`
- Refer to extracted value as `${token}` or `${__V(token)}` where required. Same restriction on JMeter Variables scope apply.

See [JSoup selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) guide for a reference on how to build CSS selectors.

Hope this helps.